# Load Image Into ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to load an image from my local server into an image view using glide. The url i am using works fine. When i look for it in the browser the image loads, but when i use it in the code the glide does not load the image.

```
package knife.butter.glide;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    Glide.with(v.getContext())
                            .load("http://192.168.1.191/driver/uploads/driver.jpg")
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .into(imageView);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Check if there is image in the URL you have provided 2. Check if you're getting any exception

Comment: You should print the exception to the logs rather than a Toast so that you can copy it here

Comment: Also, you'll need the internet permission in your manifest

Comment: cricket_007, thank you so much I had missed the internet permission in the manifest. It worked successfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, use inbuilt listener of `glide` for checking Exception.

```
Glide.with(v.getContext())
     .load("http://192.168.1.191/driver/uploads/driver.jpg")
     .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
         @Override
         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             Log.e("Error","invalid Image Link");
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
             return false;
         }
     })
     .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
     .into(imageView);
```

**Note :**

Make sure you have Given permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your manifest.xml

Happy Coding..